# get array duplicates if the repeating items not next to each other

Tags: javascript

I want to get array duplicates so I have this code:

```js
const reference = ['we', 'we', 'did', 'something']
const duplicateRefs = reference.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i);
console.log(duplicateRefs);
```

The issue is I just want to get the duplicates Only if they are not next to each other.

so for this array I should get an empty array: `['we', 'we', 'did', 'something']`

And for this one I should get `['we']` as the duplicates: `['we', 'did', 'we', 'something']`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of searching for a match with `index !== i`, search for `index < i-1`:

```js
const reference = ['we', 'did', 'we', 'something', 'something', 'did']
const duplicateRefs = reference.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) < i-1);
console.log(duplicateRefs);
```